# OneDrive for business - How can I manage, by the PHP Rest API, the permissions on folders?

Tags: php, office365, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I actually try to manage Folders, Files, Users, Groups and permissions between them by a PHP Rest API.
I can manage : Folders and Files by the OneDrive Rest API.
I can manage : Users and Groups by the Azure AD Rest API.

But I can't manage permissions between them...
I saw that with OneDrive API I can generate a sharing link, but it's not what I want. 
I want to manage permissions without external interventions.
I tried to find it on the SharePoint API, but apparently it does not discuss with onedrive folders.

Does someone know how to manage them ?